# PHP Facebook Authentication

Tags: php, facebook

I want users to be able to log in with Facebook.

Does anyone know a tutorial that actually works and doesn't have errors in it?

I am currently using this tutorial:
http://www.barattalo.it/facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Please stop using tutorials dated couple of years ago! [Facebook Developers documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) is the only somehow credible source for documentation. Platform is changing too quickly (even official documentation have some issues and not always updated to the latest changes)...

Comment: Im not that advanced in PHP and I want to some extra things, so following a tutorial would be good.

Comment: Following an old out of date tutorial will drive you crazy.  Facebook has plenty of walk thrus and tutorials to get you going.  Also the PHP SDK (https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) has it's own examples (which are up to date most of the time) at https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/examples.

Answer (score 3):

There is official tutorial for [Server-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).

It may be useful also to read [Authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial: http://aniri.ro/geek/tutorials/how-to-make-website-registration-easier-using-facebook-accounts/

I've no idea if it's outdated, but demo works fine. You can download all files and follow instruction from site.

Enjoy!